# Suddenly Stops working: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

EDIT: I have attached a copy of the spreadsheet on an alternative account. So far, regardless of solutions offered or links to other answers, I am still getting the same problem.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1feRQ7txV5dI-7Ein66-Z6LjF5w8vdmtw8gACk_motic/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT 2: Screenshot provided below showing execution screenshot. This was triggered in `P3` using col===57

[image]

I've read through a bunch of answers on StackOverflow, and none seem to fit what's going on here and it's really throwing me for a loop. Hopefully someone can help!

This script worked for 3 months. The ONLY changes made were to the var tc numbers (i.e., which column to check as a trigger). Nothing else has changed. The strangest part of all... if lines 6-25 are triggered, everything works. If lines 26-45 are triggered, I get an error. So I'm at a loss at why this would stop working when it was working for 3 months, part of it works but the other doesn't, and I haven't changed any names/labels in the sheet or in the script.

(btw, I did check the common fixes such as ensuring the sheet names are 100% identical, including case, spaces, etc)

**What is supposed to happen:**

In a given sheet, when someone selects `TRUE` on a specific checkbox, indicated by column, the row in that sheet is moved to the next sheet in the workflow. For example, if "Prospect" line 21 is marked true, it moves to "Pricing" and is then deleted from "Prospects".

**What is happening right now:**

Everything works for Prospects -> Pricing, Pricing -> Onboarding, and Onboarding -> DASH.
Nothing works for ADMIN -> BOOKS, BOOKS -> PREP, PREP -> REVIEW, REVIEW - FILING. Instead I get the following error message:

Feb 9, 2022, 4:19:23 PM Error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
at onEdit(Code:56:47)

EDIT: Added image of the sheets being used for reference. Metrics is not used in this script so can be ignored.
[image]

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = event.range;
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = s.getName();
  if (sheetName == "Prospects") {
    var ts = "Pricing";
    var as = "ARCHIVED";
    var tc = 11;
    var bc = 200;
    var ar = 45
  } else if (sheetName == "Pricing") {
    var ps = "Prospects";
    var ts = "Onboarding";
    var as = "ARCHIVED";
    var tc = 34;
    var bc = 11;
    var ar = 45
  } else if (sheetName == "Onboarding") {
    var ps = "Pricing";
    var ts = "DASH";
    var as = "ARCHIVED";
    var tc = 46;
    var bc = 34;
    var ar = 45
  } else if (sheetName == "ADMIN") {
    var ps = "DASH";
    var ts = "BOOKS";
    var tc = 55;
    var bc = 500;
  } else if (sheetName == "BOOKS") {
    var ps = "ADMIN";
    var ts = "PREP";
    var tc = 56;
    var bc = 10;
  } else if (sheetName == "PREP") {
    var ps = "BOOKS";
    var ts = "REVIEW";
    var tc = 57;
    var bc = 11;
  } else if (sheetName == "REVIEW") {
    var ps = "PREP";
    var ts = "FILING";
    var tc = 58;
    var bc = 12;
  }

  var targetSheet = "";
  if (r.getColumn() == tc && event.value == "TRUE") {
    targetSheet = ts;
  } else if (r.getColumn() == bc && event.value == "FALSE") {
    targetSheet = ps;
  }  else if (r.getColumn() == ar && event.value == "TRUE") {
    targetSheet = as;
  }
  var lastRow = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow()
  var row = r.getRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var target = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet).getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);
```

Comment: Are you sure all your conditions are met?  I would put a SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(targetSheet); before var lastRow = and see what you got.

Comment: Maybe it runs out of time

Comment: Prospects does not have a ps

Comment: Prospects does not have a ps because ps moves things backwards, and nothing can move back from the first step.

Comment: I will try the options above, but again the big question mark for me is that this exact script, minus the change today of increasing the var tc by 2, worked for over 3 months. So something else must be up, as the conditions obviously worked for that entire time period

Comment: When I add SpreadsheetApp.getUi()alert(targetSheet); and try to trigger from REVIEW I get a return of `FILING` which is correct. So the condition seems to be met and is returning the correct sheet

Comment: There is only one reason for `null`. The Sheet name is incorrect. Check for spaces, non printable characters in the sheet name. Alternatively, Rename the sheet to something simple like S1. Also try a new function: `console.log(ss.getSheetByName('FILING'))`

Comment: @TheMaster I tried changing the sheet names to something simple, A1, B2, P3, R4, F5. I am having the same issue. That's what is so confusing, because when I run a function to return the sheet name, I get a correct response back. When I run this script, it only gives me correct responses for the first few sheets but not for these.

Comment: Add `console.log({targetSheet})` before line 57.  Conditions are not satisfied. targetSheet is empty and therefore you get the error. If `A1`'s J column("Move to Admin") is edited (col===10), none of the conditions for `tc`,`bc` or `ar` is satisfied. You need to provide [mcve].

Comment: `A1` col===10 is not a trigger... col===55 is the trigger.

I ran the console.log and see it returns null, but I don't understand why. Why would it work for `Prospects`, `Pricing`, `Onboarding`, `DASH`, but not for `A1`, `B2`, `P3`, `R4`, and `F5`?

Comment: Even if `A1`col==55 is the trigger, `targetSheet` will be `B1`, but there is no sheet named `B1` in your spreadsheet. So it is `null`. Provide [mcve].

Comment: Apologies, I see I mistyped that - I changed it to the correct `B2` and am still getting an error. Same if I trigger off of P3 or R4 (I've reviewed and ensured they are all correctly named). So when the trigger is used, `targetSheet` should be `B2`, which there is a sheet named `B2`, but the log is returning null still.

Comment: Provide Screenshot of your executions

Comment: Screenshot added

Comment: Edited the duplicate list. As you can see, the problem was never about getRange of null, but about `Timed out`

Comment: @TheMaster THANK YOU! Looks like it was the bug where the first column can't be hidden. I appreciate the help, I didn't even know to ask about that since I didn't think that would cause a failure. Thank you again

Comment: @JoshKreuer  You're welcome. Debugging is a art and it comes by practice. Do read [mcve] and practice the steps mentioned there, whenever you run into an another problem.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you, I will! I am learning a lot from you and the others here. I really do appreciate it and hopefully will be able to help others as I continue learning. I will definitely read that and practice following it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const vA = [{ name: "Prospects", ps: "", ts: "Pricing", as: "ARCHIVED", tc: 11, bc: 200, ar: 45 }, { name: "Pricing", ps: "Prospects", ts: "Onboarding", as: "ARCHIVED", tc: 34, bc: 11, ar: 45 }];//need to fill in the rest of the array
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const name = sh.getName();
  for (let i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
    if (name == vA[i].name) {
      let tshname;
      if (e.range.columnStart == vA[i].tc && e.value == "TRUE") {
        tshname = vA[i].ts;
      } else if (e.range.columnStart == vA[i].bc && e.value == "FALSE") {
        tshname = vA[i].ps;
      } else if (r.range.columnStart == vA[i].ar && e.value == "TRUE") {
        tshname = vA[i].as;
      }
      let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(tshname);
      let lastRow = tsh.getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow()
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tsh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1));
      sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to complete the vA array.

Comment: I tried this script and surprisingly it has the exact same problem I had with the original code - it works for Prospects through Dash, but Admin through Filing get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
    at onEdit(Code:16:25)